# Counterexample to disprove that $P(A-B) = P(A) - P(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

Assuming $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$, would this be a correct counterexample for the statement that $P(A-B) = P(A) - P(B)$?

---

Let $A = \{2, 3\}$ and $B = \{2\}$, therefore $C = \{3\}$.

$P(A-B) = P(C) = \{\{3\}, \{\varnothing\}\}$

\begin{align*}
P(A) - P(B) &= \{\{2, 3\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{\varnothing\}\} - \{\{2\}, \{\varnothing\}\} \\
            &= \{\{2, 3\}, \{3\}\}
\end{align*}

As shown, $P(A-B)$ contains the empty set while $P(A) - P(B)$ does not and as such:

$$P(A-B) \ne P(A) - P(B)$$

Comment: Looks good to me. You could even just say that in general, the empty set is not an element of $P(A)\setminus P(B)$ for any $A,B$ whereas $P(A\setminus B)$ would contain the empty set as an element.

Comment: An even simpler example would be $A=B=\varnothing$.

Comment: It is always $$P(A-B) \ne P(A) - P(B)$$ because the lhs contains the empty set and the rhs does not.

Answer (score 1):

*Comments from Cameron Williams and Asaf Karagila were incorporated in this answer.*

Yes that would work.

In fact, $P(A) - P(B)$ never contains the empty set (as $\varnothing \in P(B)$), so any $A$ and $B$ suffice (even $A = B = \varnothing$).